# Audit in Camel Route

Tags: apache, apache-camel

It is kind of lengthy description, apologies for that.

I have a requirement for a Camel route where we have strict audit requirements of each step, regardless of success or failure.

A typical route is:

EndpointA -> Queue1 -> Transformation -> Queue2 -> EndpointB

We have to audit after each successful commit at the Queues. Please note that there are many many routes like aboove and each will have different queue names.

One solution is:

EndpointA -> Queue1 -> AuditQueue -> Transformation -> Queue2 -> AuditQueue -> EndpointB -> AuditQueue

But the solution looks bad as I have to put another AuditQueue in the main route to solve this issue.

If I change the Queue1, Queue2 etc. to topics, then I have to write multiple consumers (I mean multiple routes with multiple from (like from(Queue1), from (Queue2) etc.) so that I can audit the messages in each step. What I am looking is a re-usable and elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
 Sreejesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Camel's [`EventNotifierSupport`](http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html) and ExchangeSentEvent.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of our main routes, we use [`onCompletion`](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) facility. It's always triggered when the exchange is complete, success or failed. It can be configured with a global or a per route scope.

For example

```
    from("direct:mainRoute").routeId("mainRoute")
        .onCompletion()
            .to("direct:completionRoute")
            .process(myCompletionProcessor)
        .end()
```